# Can a Trezor accept/use a private key created independently offline?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, trezor

Can I create a private key using bitaddress.org offline and then use that private key in a trezor wallet? Also will the trezor use that private key to produce a mnemonic phrase?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import individual private keys into a Trezor. However you can generate your own mnemonic offline and import that into a Trezor.

Comment: awesome thanks...how do you gnereate your own mnemonic?

Comment: Own mnemonic can be generated using the Seed Tool: https://bitcoiner.guide/seed/